# XMLReader ReadToFollowing returns None

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader

Here's the XML

```
     <GeoLoc>
      <Location>
          <AddrLn1>384-393 COMMERCIAL ROAD</AddrLn1>
          <Town>LONDON</Town>
          <PostCode>E1 0LR</PostCode>
          <Country>ENGLAND</Country>
          <UPRN>100080712803</UPRN>
        </Location>
      </GeoLoc>
```

Here's my subroutine

```
private GeoLoc GetGeoLoc(XmlReader reader)
    {
        GeoLoc _geoloc = new GeoLoc();
        _geoloc.Location = new Location();
        


        if (reader.ReadToDescendant("Location"))
        {
            if (reader.ReadToFollowing("AddrLn1"))
            {
                _geoloc.Location.AddrLn1 = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
            }
            if (reader.ReadToFollowing("AddrLn2"))
            {
                _geoloc.Location.AddrLn2 = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
            }
            if (reader.ReadToFollowing("AddrLn3"))
            {
                _geoloc.Location.AddrLn3 = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
            }
            if (reader.ReadToFollowing("Town"))
            {
                _geoloc.Location.Town = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
            }
            if (reader.ReadToFollowing("County"))
            {
                _geoloc.Location.County = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
            }
            if (reader.ReadToFollowing("PostCode"))
            {
                _geoloc.Location.PostCode = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
            }
            if (reader.ReadToFollowing("Country"))
            {
                _geoloc.Location.Country = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
            }
            if (reader.ReadToFollowing("UPRN"))
            {
                _geoloc.Location.UPRN = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
            }
        }
        return _geoloc;
    }
```

The problem is it only reads AddrLn1 then after that reader becomes none. I tried the ReadSubTree() but has the same result. Please note that some tags could be missing on some Geoloc example AddrLn2 or AddrLn3 could be present.

Comment: Problem is there is no address line 2 so you are going to end of file and not finding anything. You can use following : XmlReader child = reader.ReadSubtree();

Comment: Thanks @jdweng, where should I add this? and how would I check so I can skip elements that are missing?

Comment: The reader will be at EOF if item is not found.  Or you could move to next element.

Comment: You need two reader so when you do not find an item you are still at current location. XmlReader child = reader.ReadSubtree();  if (child.ReadToFollowing("Country")) { reader = child; _geoloc.Location.County = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();}

Comment: So I tried that but when inner.ReadElementContentAsString(); gets executed both reader and child reader becomes "Whitespace, Value=\"          \""

Answer (score 1):

I usually use XML Linq along with an XmlReader.  You will get an empty string if not found.

```
           if (reader.ReadToDescendant("Location"))
            {
                XElement location = (XElement)XElement.ReadFrom(reader);

                string addrLn1 = (string)location.Element("AddrLn1");
                string addrLn2 = (string)location.Element("AddrLn2");
                string addrLn3 = (string)location.Element("AddrLn3");

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Update: Initially the below code works for me but I found a much better solution

```
private GeoLoc GetGeoLoc(XmlReader reader)
{
    GeoLoc _geoloc = new GeoLoc();
    _geoloc.Location = new Location();

    if (reader.ReadToDescendant("Location"))
    {
        do
        {
            reader.Read();
            reader.MoveToContent();
            switch (reader.LocalName)
            {
                case "AddrLn1":
                    _geoloc.Location.AddrLn1 = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                    break;
                case "AddrLn2":
                    _geoloc.Location.AddrLn2 = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                    break;
                case "AddrLn3":
                    _geoloc.Location.AddrLn3 = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                    break;
                case "Town":
                    _geoloc.Location.Town = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                    break;
                case "County":
                    _geoloc.Location.County = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                    break;
                case "PostCode":
                    _geoloc.Location.PostCode = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                    break;
                case "Country":
                    _geoloc.Location.Country = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                    break;
                case "UPRN":
                    _geoloc.Location.Country = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                    break;
            }

        } while (reader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.None);
        
    }
    return _geoloc;
}
```

Here's the new code, rather than using reader, I decided to use XElement. performance is the same.

```
private GeoLoc GetGeoLoc(XElement element)
{
    GeoLoc _geoloc = new GeoLoc();
    _geoloc.Location = new Location();
    foreach (XElement geolocel in element.Elements())
    {
        foreach (XElement locationel in geolocel.Elements())
        {
            switch (locationel.Name.LocalName)
            {
                case "AddrLn1":
                    _geoloc.Location.AddrLn1 = locationel.Value;
                    break;
                case "AddrLn2":
                    _geoloc.Location.AddrLn2 = locationel.Value;
                    break;
                case "AddrLn3":
                    _geoloc.Location.AddrLn3 = locationel.Value;
                    break;
                case "Town":
                    _geoloc.Location.Town = locationel.Value;
                    break;
                case "County":
                    _geoloc.Location.County = locationel.Value;
                    break;
                case "PostCode":
                    _geoloc.Location.PostCode = locationel.Value;
                    break;
                case "Country":
                    _geoloc.Location.Country = locationel.Value;
                    break;
                case "UPRN":
                    _geoloc.Location.Country = locationel.Value;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    return _geoloc;

}
```